# How do I set up navigation using CFINCLUDE with subfolders?

Tags: html, coldfusion

I want to set up a page with navigation links in ColdFusion and us CFINCLUDE to pull the navigation in on each individual page. If I keep all the pages in the root folder the navigation works fine, but I want to organize my pages in sub folders. When I link to:

```
<a href="pages/page2.cfm">Page 2</a>
```

I go to page two but when trying to get back to:

```
<a href="page1.cfm">Page 1</a>
```

I get the following error: File not found: navigationtest/pages/page1.cfm.

I know you need to use ../ and if I put the navigation on each individual page like that it works with the subfolders, but I want one page with navigation and INCLUDE it on all my other pages.

How can I set up my Navigation so it works with subfolders in ColdFusion?

This is my file structure:

[image]

This is my include page:

[image]

This is my page code (same on all pages except in the body it's the respective page name (i.e. - default, page1, page2):

[image]

Comment: What happens if you change this:  `<a href="page1.cfm">` to this: `<a href="page1.cfm">`?

Comment: Oops, I meant this:  `<a href="../page1.cfm">`

Comment: It works if I'm on page2.cfm (goes to page1.cfm) but then if I'm on the default.cfm page and try to go to page1.cfm I get an error.

Comment: The problem is navigating in and out of a subfolder(s). Ultimately I want several subfolders with multiple pages each.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a global layout file, a file that starts your `<html>` tags, add a `<base href="{domain}" >` tag and all anchor (`<a>`) tags will use that as the root for all links, images, etc.

Alternately, you can change all of your link, image, etc. `href` values to start with a leading slash. This tells the browser to start at the root of the website and look from there.

So instead of

```
<a href="page1.cfm">Page 1</a>
```

use

```
<a href="/page1.cfm">Page 1</a>
```

Then if you're in the 3rd level folder, the link to page1.cfm will always look from the root of the website instead of relative to the current folder, which is what's happening now.

Personally, I would use a framework like [ColdBox](http://www.coldbox.org/) or [FW/1](http://framework-one.github.io/), where all URLs are driven from the root and layouts can be handled without all the `CFINCLUDE`s all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

I would setup all your navigation links to start with root. Like this:

```
<a href="/default.cfm">Home</a>
<a href="/page1.cfm">Page 1</a>
<a href="/pages/page2.cfm">Page 2</a>
```

So even if you are on Page 2, the browser will look for page1.cfm in the root instead of in the /pages folder.

Comment: Are these example pages not in the root of your website? For example, is the full address to page1.cfm something like http://www.example.com/subDir1/page1.cfm? If so, then you would need to change the code to <a href="/subDir1/page1.cfm">Page 1</a>.